# How to avoid insert a property class into SQL database in C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, class, properties

I'm having troubles when I do a POST endpoint.

When I run the code to insert data into my database, it breaks because of an invalid column name; I'm inserting the class entity that has an extra property (that is always null, except when I'm bringing it from another table with an inner join). This property is read as a column from the entity that I'm trying to insert and it breaks.

There is a way to ignore this property? I'm not using Entity Framework, I've tried a few ways already. That is why I'm asking.

EDIT: I'm having these error for INSERTS and UPDATES because I'm saving the entity that has 1 extra property that doesn't match with the table. My question is, there is any way to ignore it for these cases?

await _clientRepository.UpdateAsync(client);-> this line breaks because client.Description doesn't exists in the sql table.

`[NotMapped]` -> didn't work.

Comment: You need to provide some code so we can help, it's like walk in dark to investigate such problems.

Comment: Which library you are using for inserting object into db? You can try making the property as a private member.

Comment: You should always test your quires using SQL Server Management Studio before using them in c#.  The SSMS error message are much better than the c# errors.

Comment: If you insert kind of mapped class properties into an SQL-Database, and you use not EntityFramework, then you must use something else to Map it. What is it ? Why do you even try to use the EF-Atttribute "NotMapped" if you say you are not using Entity Framework. Are you sure you are not using it ?